# rails 3 polymorphic routing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, model-view-controller, polymorphism, rails-routing

Been trying to find an answer to this question for a while, decided it was worth asking a new one...

I have multiple models which are polymorphic, defined like: `class Transport`, `class Transport::Car < Transport`, `class Transport::Plane < Transport`

I have a base `TransportController`, and then every type of`Transport` has a corresponding controller (all under the `Transport` namespace), i.e. `Transport::CarController`, `Transport::PlaneController`.

I want to figure out how to create routing for the different `Transport` actions...

- I do not know a priori how many `Transport` sub-classes I will have (this is done as part of an initializer via a database call).
- For every `Transport`, there are two shared controller actions, call them `#board` and `#depart`. These methods should live inside `TransportController` because they perform the same actions and display the same view,  regardless of the type of Transport.
- Different `Transport` types can have different implementations of their own actions. For example `#choose_seat` for a car and plane are different with different constraints and different views, but the action is the same.
- Different `Transport` types are entitled to have unique actions. For example `Transport::PlaneController` should have a `#landing_gear_up` action whereas this does not make sense for `Transport::CarController`.

What I might like is a routing file like:

```
# for an action landing_gear_up only inside plane
match '/transport/plane/landing_gear_up',
      :controller => "Transport::PlaneController",
      :action => "landing_gear_up"

# for an action on every transport type that are handled differently
match '/transport/:type/choose_seat',
      :controller => "Transport::<type>Controller",
      :action => "choose_seat"

# for the actions that are handled commonly across every type of transport
match '/transport/:type/board', :to => "transport#board"
match '/transport/:type/depart', :to => "transport#depart"
```

I feel like this should be possible with "dynamic segments" but I can't manage to get it to work properly. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

You can define methods and variables in `routes.rb` that can make the code more DRY. An example of how I would try to do it:

```
Your::Application.routes.draw do
  ## other routes

  ## helper method to define transport route
  def route_transport action, types
    match "/transport/:type/#{action}", :to => "transport##{action}" and return if types == :common
    [types].flatten.each { |t| match "/transport/#{t}/#{action}", :controller => "Transport::#{t}Controller", :action => action }
  end

  {
    :board => :common,
    :depart => :common,
    :landing_gear_up => :plane,
    :choose_seat => [:car, :plane],
    # action name => :common or transport type(s)
  }.each { |action, types| route_transport action, types }

  ## other routes
end
```

I did not check the code, it might contain errors. Run `rake routes` to check whether the correct routes are being generated.

Also, take a look at [RESTful routes](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#resource-routing-the-rails-default) -- they might make your life easier in the long run.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the same inheritance hierarchy in controllers, then you don't have to do anything special. Just declare resources, declare the non-RESTful routes for each Controller and you are done. PlaneController#board will automatically call TransportController#board. And actions specific to PlaneController will remain specific to that controller.